# Private beta now shows on network profile; should it?

Tags: support, network-profile, private-beta

Private beta sites aren't *really* private, in that anybody can join via Area 51.  But they've always been "mostly private"; they don't show up in users' network profiles, the hamburger list, the [list of all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#oldest), or migration options (for moderators).  They're there, but the paths to them are limited.

Most of that is still true, but today private beta sites *do* show up on the network profile.  Here's an [example](https://stackexchange.com/users/34933/robert-cartaino?tab=accounts):

[image: network profile excerpt]

If you follow the link you still get this, as expected:

[image: this site is in private beta]
When I've been a user on private betas I've been frustrated that I didn't have convenient access from the rest of the network, so this might well be intentional.  On the other hand, private betas still don't show up on the list of all sites, so maybe it wasn't intended.

Comment: No repro. Maybe only moderators see those, same way they see hidden communities. Try visiting your profile in Incognito Mode and see for yourself.

Comment: @Shadow I can repro (on Robert Cartaino's profile). This happens even when logged out.

Comment: Pretty sure nothing's changed there and they've always been shown. Or do I misremember and this is actually something recent?

Comment: @AdamLear the last time I was part of a private beta (trying to remember when that was), I couldn't get to it from my network profile and kept a separate tab open to it for the duration.